# Using an appropriate key for caching

Tags: caching, grails

Say I want to cache employee data.  EmployeeId is the primary key in the database.  So, is it alright to use EmployeeId as the key for cache? i.e.,

cache.put(employee.getId(), employee); // employee is an instance of class Employee

Or does the key have to be more complex (generated using some hashing algorithm, etc.)?  Is there any harm in using employeeId as the cache key?

Comment: If it is Java then use Java tag. And describe your problem with more details.

Comment: It is a grails application.  Can you please share more details on java tags?

Comment: @AnandJayabalan - they meant that you can have up to 5 tags on your question. I've added one for [tag:grails].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No harm in using employeeId as the key but its better to prefix this with something like `Employee` so that another Object in the cache with same id doesn't overwrite your employee cache entry. So something like this:

```
// employee is an instance of Employee
cache.put("Employee::" + employee.getId(), employee);
```

**EDIT:** If you dedicated buckets for each object type

```
// employee is an instance of Employee
cache.put(employee.getId(), employee);
```

Comment: I use separate buckets or maps for each type of data.  So, all employee data will be in the "EMP" bucket, vendor data would be in the "VENDOR" bucket, etc.. In this scenario, the prefix is redundant, correct?

Comment: Yes that is true, if you dedicated buckets for each object type then ignore prefix part.